# How to Implement Scene Transition Animation with Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, material-ui, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

If I dont use compose，I will use like this

```
val bundle = ActivityOptionsCompat
                .makeSceneTransitionAnimation(requireActivity(), toolbar, "llSearch").toBundle()
```

Here is one of his effects

[Android Developer example](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/animations/transitions/start-activity)

[image]
[image]

I have two pages. There is a search box at the top of the first page, which is a static interface. Clicking on it will lead to the actual search interface. The search boxes on both interfaces are roughly the same, but the width of the search box on the first interface is wider than that on the second interface. The animation effect is that when the second interface is displayed, the search box on the first interface quickly shrinks, And overlap with the search box on the second interface

These two images, the first one is page1, and the second one is page2. In page1, when navController. navigateTo (page2) is used, there is an animation effect where the search box shrinks and overlaps with the search box on page2